# Under which domain is the Finder sidebar "Devices" category setting for "User's MacBook Pro"?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, finder, terminal.app, plist

Trying to verify that "User's MacBook Pro" is in the Finder's sidebar from the Terminal. I can't find a correlating setting under `com.apple.finder`, `com.apple.sidebarlists`, or even `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences`. I've tried quitting Finder, opening it, reading the plist with `defaults`, changing the value, reading it again, quitting Finder again, and reading it again. No changes. I've even tried rebooting and using Instruments. I also tried `gdb` but it didn't work (I've contacted the webmaster of [this site](http://home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html) to get help).

I was wondering if anyone here knew this off the top of his or her head, or knew a better way to find out. I've tried [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com) and of course Google with no luck.

Comment: Will using AppleScript to open the preferences dialog and read the state of the checkbox work for you?

Comment: In all seriousness, I'd have to pick up AppleScript for something which I would assume would just be in a plist somewhere. Seems over-engineered.

Comment: FWIW I recreated the CFPreferences breakpoints successfully in Xcode without Finder crashing after I attach to the running instance. Toggling the preference is not a preference going through any of these function calls.

Comment: Thanks for the info... that's very confusing though :(